# Passing Parameter to Data Flow in Azure Data Factory

Tags: dataflow, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow which takes **startTime** and **endTime** as parameters and I am passing the values to these parameters via a pipeline using **pipeline expression** but the expression is not evaluated rather its considered[image] as string. Attached the Images

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found out the root cause,

1. **long()** is not supported in expression builder.
2. **@** is missing at the beginning of the expression.

So the working expression was which gives **CURRENT EPOCH TIME**

```
@div(sub(ticks(startOfDay(utcNow())),ticks('1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z')),10000000)
```